# compare string inside windows.alert

Tags: javascript

This might be a dumb question, but considering the following semi-pseudo code.  How do I compare the string in windws.alert?

```
var alertCalled = false;
// I'm having trouble with the following line
if (windows.alert().text == 'specific string') {
    alertCalled = true;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just wondering what is the purprose of this? If you call alert(), it's always displayed so something like your example snippet is completely unnecessary

Comment: @Jani: this is a code snippet to something bigger. I want to know the string that will be displayed on the alert box so I can override that particular alert box only. So the first step is to find out how to detect a particular string. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alert` function accepts a string as an input but does not echo it back. I am not sure but it might be possible to hook your own implementation of alert function to the native one. This worked in FireFox and IE8:

```
var alertCalled = false;
var originalAlert = window.alert;

window.alert = function( s )
{
    originalAlert( s );
    alertCalled = s == 'specific string';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to compare the string that is passed into the alert, e.g.

```
var message = "My alert message";
alert(message);
if (message == someOtherMessage) { /* do stuff */ }
```

The *alert()* function itself doesn't return anything.